# Is the composition of two optimal transport maps still optimal (under some assumptions)?

Tags: probability, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, function-and-relation-composition, optimal-transport

Consider three **absolutely continuous** probability measures $\mu$, $u$, and $\nu$ on $\mathbb R^d$ ($d \geq 1$), all of which have **finite second moments**. A transport map from $\mu$ to $\nu$ is called optimal if it is the solution to the following constrained optimization problem:

$$
\min\int \|\boldsymbol x - T(\boldsymbol x)\|_2^2 ~d \mu(\boldsymbol x) \quad \text{subject to } T_\#\mu = \nu
$$

where $T_\#\mu = \nu$ is the push forward operation meaning that if $\boldsymbol X \sim \mu$, then $T(\boldsymbol X) \sim \nu$. Also, denote $T^{\mu\nu}$ as the optimal transport map for convenience. The existence and $\mu$-a.e uniqueness is well guaranteed under stated assumptions.

**My question**: do we have some kind of transferability for optimal transport maps? That is, is $T^{\mu u} \circ T^{u \nu} = T^{\mu \nu}$ $\mu$-a.e.? If not, can someone provide a valid counterexample? Many thanks.

Some side notes:

1. The statement is true when $d = 1$, it can be proved using the monotonicity of CDFs and Brenier-McCann theorem together;
2. The result is not true if we don't assume absolute continuity. The counterexample should be easy to construct, but I am more interested in the case where the stated assumptions (bold) hold.

Comment: This is likely false. Think of a triangle ABC. AB and BC are optimal transport plans. Their composition  (i.e the path AB+BC) is definitely not (AC is).

Comment: @dohmatob Thanks for your input. I understand this triangular-inequality-like argument, but I think this is more or like the transformation of measures instead of the triangle. A concrete counterexample would be more helpful. Thanks!

Comment: If you understand this triangle inequality argument then i understand what you need more. Put dirac masses at vertices pf thé triangle, and you have your "concrete" example

Comment: Correction: I *don't* understand what you need more.

Comment: @dohmatob I meant a counterexample under the assumptions mentioned in the beginning (absolute continuity [for which Dirac measures don't meet the requirement] and finite second moment). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok sorry, Indeed i glossed over the hypotheses.